# SPFx image previewer extension

Tags: sharepoint-framework, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I am looking around to create an image previewer extension using SharePoint framework. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I am just wondering if there are some ready components which I can include in my spfx web part? Using React and probably there is something in Office UI Fabric?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Fabric UI` roadmap (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/blob/master/ghdocs/ROADMAP.md) you can find `image file` backlog item, that not even "in development", and not clear what this component will look like.

I found `react-file-upload` in `sp-dev-fx-webparts` samples:  https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-file-upload. It looks similar but not so good.

In my case it was better to create my own `image previewer`.